# webpack says WorkboxWebpackPlugin.InjectManifest is not a contructor

Tags: webpack, workbox

Trying to run webpack on my project, it says WorkboxWebpackPlugin.InjectManifest is not a constructor. I looked into github to see it is indeed there. I have installed workbox-webpack-plugin and don't understand why this isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it turned out to be the way I was importing the object for InjectManifest. It might not be your case but sharing in case it helps someone

My initial way:

```
const InjectManifest = require('workbox-webpack-plugin');
```

Correct way:

```
const {InjectManifest} = require('workbox-webpack-plugin');
```